# Is there a web site for planning your own workouts and following up on them?

Tags: workout-routines, programs, motivation, websites

Yes, there are loads of fitness sites out there. Some will let you track weight loss, some will provide a training program for you and some will let you record your workouts.

But my issue is being able to stick with whichever training schedule I have set up. I would like a web site where I can fill in my own types of workouts, plan a week of them, and even plan a season. Then I would like the site to email me and ask me if I've completed a workout, and if not, to ask me why not.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: If you're of the technically inclined DIY mindset, you could always create a LAMP stack on your home computer and write your own php script for this. Heck, you could even skip LAMP and just setup a shell script cron job!

Comment: Well, yes, I do actually develop software for a living, but I would prefer not having to reinvent the wheel and spend several hours on this. Plus, it would be nice to find a site that does this in addition to some of the many features that Fitocracy, mentioned below, has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest one is a site called [Noom](http://www.noom.com/).  It's a diet/exercise site but it will send notifications to you to inform you of upcoming exercises and helps you keep your schedule.

I use [MapMyRun](http://www.mapmyrun.com/) to plan my workouts, and I can upload my Garmin GPS data to the site to show what I've done.

Other sites could include [SuperBetter](https://www.superbetter.com/), [Fitocracy](http://www.Fitocracy.com), [RunKeeper](http://runkeeper.com/), [FitBit](http://www.fitbit.com/), [SparkPeople](http://www.sparkpeople.com/) or [Adidas MiCoach](http://www.adidas.com/us/micoach/).

Comment: See this meta question for a longer list, http://meta.fitness.stackexchange.com/a/210/3778 of sites. The degree of planning support is changing.

Answer (score 0):

[Fitocracy](http://www.Fitocracy.com) has some functionality like that, in that you can schedule workouts for the future and then follow up and put in that you actually did it.  I'm not sure how far into the future you can go though.

Comment: Are you sure? Going through the "Getting started" guide, they talk about tracking workouts for today or a week back, but there's no mention of any future scheduling, nor of any following up on scheduled workouts. But Fitocracy does look slick!

Comment: i'm just recalling from what i did before, they may have gotten rid of that since then.